# Retrieve RTC time from DVB-C

Tags: raspbian

I'm using my Pi as a media center and video recorder from cable. I will now for some time have to use the Pi without internet and therefore without timeservers.

But as far as I know the DVB-C signal also contains time information and the Pi could retrieve it somehow but I haven't found a hint if/how this could be done.

DVB-C is retrieved with a [WinTV 930C](http://www.hauppauge.co.uk/site/products/data_hvr930c.html) USB-stick

Comment: You could also consider using a real time clock (RTC).

Comment: @SteveRobillard As it will be only a short period of time without internet I think it wouldn't be worth the effort

Comment: OK, stupid question then why worry about the time at all then?

Comment: @SteveRobillard The Pi should be able to show correctly which TV shows are currently running and maybe record one

Answer (score 1):

Probably the tool `dvbdate` is what you need.
Use `dvbdate -s` or alternatively `dvbdate -sf` if your local time is very offsync.

In ARCH that tool is included in "community/linuxtv-dvb-apps". In debian it seems to be included in dvb-apps".

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you're not going to be able to get the time information from the DVB-C. The company that builds the tuner you listed doesn't provide an interface to interact with its hardware.

It's theoretically possible to reverse engineer the software provided, but it'd be a ton of work, and I can't guarantee that the hardware even has the ability to provide the current time. Just because the signal provides it doesn't mean the hardware shares it.

It would be much simpler, and far more reliable to install an RTC like Steve suggested.